# How do I support more mobile viewport widths on CSS3-enabled website and force mobile browser to use the proper width?

Tags: mobile, css, viewport, media-queries

I have website with fixed width of 1000px. I want to support 2 smaller widths of this page. I have succesfully done this through CSS media-queries like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 800px) and (max-width : 999px) {
  #content { width:800px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 799px) {
  #content { width:600px; }
}
```

Now when I test my webpage on Android browser (2.3.3), it uses viewport width of 1000px so it displays website in full width. But it would be much better, if it would chosen viewport width of 800px, because webpage would display more optimized for device with smaller displays.

I know I can set viewport width using e.g.: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=800px" />` or to set width coresponding to device physical width using: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`, but none of these would work. Because either it would force all mobile devices to always use 800px viewport in first case, or it would use physical width of pixels on device in second case, but that wouldn't work out too, because in portrait mode (how most people surf mobile web and use phone) that would be 300px or at most 400px, which is too small and user would have to scroll horizontally a lot.

So actually my question is this - can I support and possibly force mobile browsers to use different viewport widths depending on their actual screen size ? I don't know if I explained it properly enough, so I will get example what I want to achieve:

For mobile devices with physical width of 400px (modern devices with bigger displays) I would like to force viewport of 800px width and possibly with scale 0.5 so on first page visit would be displayed full without need of horizontal scrolling and with user option to zoom in to parts of the page.

For mobile devices with physical width of 300px ( some middle-class and low-end devices ) or smaller - I would like to force viewport of 600px width and possibly with scale 0.5 so on first visit would be displayed full or at least most of it on screen with little horizontal scrolling needed. And of course, user could zoom in to parts of the page.

Is this possible set up using just CSS or CSS3 ? I can imagine JS solution, but I would like to implement this just using CSS.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am looking to do the exact thing.

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I do understand some part of your question...I have mainly worked on iPhone / iPad devices and less on Android ones...

I would recommend using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

to set the viewport based on devoce width..

Now even though you say, it would not work on orientation change, on the iPhone/iPad, the device width is always 768px whatever be the orientation.

So atleast on those devices, setting to device width would be fine..

For the Android devices, i am not really sure if the device width is returned different in each orientations..
My guess is it should be the same.

Could you please try setting the meta tag as above and see if it works fine. if no, i would be able to suggest some other way..

Thank you.

Comment: That is exactly what I don't want to do. Because if I would use "width=device-width" then mobile phone with viewport width of 300px would see just half of 600px page. But my desired goal is that this device would see half zoomed-out page (600px width page scaled to 300px physical device width).

Comment: Ok...so you can combine the meta statement by adding initial-zoom as 0.5 which should scale down to be able to see the entire page..

Comment: I can't, because I don't want to set this for all devices, that's also the reason why I asked this question. Setting initial-zoom 0.5 wouldn't make any sense for device with larger screens, e.g. 800px. Then the page would render ridiculously small. The reason I have asked this question was that I want to use media-queries suitable for multiple viewports.

Comment: Hmm...So you want to set the viewport scale only for smaller screen devices...The alternative which I could think is using server-side techniques like Java/JSP (since a meta tag is otherwise applied globally for all devices).. Basically this would involve detecting where the request is coming from (mobile/tablet)...For detection, you can try WURFL (http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/). Once you have that information, you can  dynamically include different head sections (e.g. desktop.jsp/mobile.jsp/tablet.jsp). Each of these head sections would have different meta viewport settings i.e.the way u want

Comment: I know the description is at a broad level, but that is the way it is...There is a good tutorial available on the same which can give you some good information on this..It is called as DesignMobileWeb and is available on the App Store..For server-side, java is just an example...you may use any other yechnology as well..

Comment: I actually know about this possibility to detect device upon UA string. However I would like more "clean" solution based on CSS rather then implementing parsing UA string on every page request or setting cookie. But I am ready to implement if no better solution appears here...

Comment: Well...the thing which u want to do cannot be really controlled by the CSS only...Thus there is some server-side mechanism which is needed, which would push only the relevant details to the client for rendering...

Answer (score 4):

just add a few more media queries and css zoom

```
//base setting, overwrite with other queries
#content { width:800px; }

@media only screen and (max-width : 799px) {
  #content { width:600px; }
}

@media only screen and  (min-width : 400px) and (max-width :599px) {
  #content { width:800px;}
//don't need to set zoom as it is handled by the next media query

}
@media only screen and (max-width : 599px}
  body{zoom:200%} 
//don't need to set #content as it has a default value of 600 set in the first media query.
}
```

You could also set initial-scale by doing user-agent sniffing, or adding it via javascript based on widow size, however via css only, you could use zoom to zoom in (user can always zoom out)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Css that may help you:

```
// target small screens (mobile devices or small desktop windows)  
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {  
/* CSS goes here */  
}  

/* high resolution screens */  
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),  
         (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),  
         (min-resolution: 300dpi) {  
header { background-image: url(header-highres.png); }  
}  

/* low resolution screens */  
@media (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
         (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
         (max-resolution: 299dpi) {  
header { background-image: url(header-lowres.png); }  
}
```

If not have a read through this link

http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/using-mobile-specific-html-css-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply zooming completely out, then letting the user scale in to see whatever it is you want?

Try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=0.25,height=device-height,user-scalable=yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in javascript by getting the viewport element (either by id or name) and setting it by inspecting the screen.width or window.outerWidth on the fly.

```
function setViewport() {
    var viewport = document.getElemementById("viewport");


    if(window.outerWidth <= 400) {
        //screen.width gives display pixel count, use window.outerWidth for physical pixel count.
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=800);
    } 
}
```